# How to sort and retain the results of a webservice?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparable

I have a class which has a list of objects in it. I need to sort the list based on the float value of list's objects but the following code does not work, after using Array.sort method I print out the collection but the students list would not be sorted based on GPAs.

School class

```
public class School{

  private List<Student> students;
  public School(){
     this.students = new ArrayList();
  }
}
```

Student class

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

 private int id;
 private float GPA;
 ...
 public int compareTo(Student student) {
        float compareGPA = student.getGPA();
        return (int)(this.getGPA() - compareGPA);
 }

}
```

Code to sort which is in main method

```
  Arrays.sort(this.school.getStudents().toArray());
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a good problem description.

Comment: @qqilihq thanks I added more details

Comment: After re-reading your last line, the issue is: `#toArray` creates a new array from the List. Only the array is sorted, not the List itself (which is, what you obviously want). See @donfoxx's answer below on how to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort like this:

```
 Collections.sort(this.school.getStudents());
```

and you should specify `<Student>` here as well:

```
 this.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are sorting an intermediate result - an array that is not stored anywhere - and you are not doing anything with it.

What you are basically doing now is:

```
Object[] intermediate = this.school.getStudents().toArray();
Arrays.sort(intermediate);
//do nothing with intermediate
```

The solution will be to use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) instead (better) - or to store the intermediate array, sort it, and then revert it back to your `students` list (worse)

Answer (score 1):

`this.school.getStudents().toArray()` creates a temporary array instance and `Array.sort()` sorts the temporary array, not your actual `ArrayList`. You could use `Collections.sort(this.school.getStudents());` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `Collections.sort(this.school.getStudents());` or  `Collections.reverse(this.school.getStudents());` for ascending and descending order respectively.